# Android studio packaging error, request support

Tags: android

Error message:

> CDATA 节中找到无效的 XML 字符 (Unicode 0x10)

When I in Android studio packaging projects to the question, then I apk pack has been unable to succeed. This seems to be wrong XML, but there's no way to locate a particular XML, how to solve.

Comment: Unfortunately the studio doesn't give you many options to deal with XML errors (capital letters in the names or ids is the most common error). what you can do is run the gradle console with stacktrace. I think thats the best option so solve xml errors

Answer (score 0):

open gradle console and write: `gradle --stacktrace`. it will show you where gradle fails to compile.